# Changing variables with another program

Tags: c, variables, system

I am trying to have another program modify variables I send to it. My attempt at this is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
char *margs[3];
pid_t pid;
margs[0] = "child.out";
margs[1] = "4";
margs[2] = NULL;

system("gcc testc.c -o child.out");

switch ((pid = vfork()))
{
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
        break;
    case 0:
        execv("child.out", margs);
        printf("SHOULD NOT PRINT\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    default:
        waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
        break;
}

printf("%s\n", margs[1]);
return 0;

}
```

with testc.c reading

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
argv[1] = "3";
return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this it prints out "4" and not "3".
Or maybe there's a better way to access information from the second program than what I'm trying to do here. I need the first program to call gcc and compile the second, as I'm doing above.
Any ideas?

Comment: that should be `char *margs[3];`

Comment: Oops, thanks. Corrected it and it still behaves the same way :(.

Comment: forked processes don't share memory, you have to use [inter process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: @user26347 Actually, a `fork()`ed process does share it's parents memory address space. It's the `exec()` that detaches from the parent address space and creates a new one for the new process...

Comment: Thank you, I found http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html which I think will solve my problem.

Comment: @twalberg - incorrect. The fork child gets a **copy** of the parent's address space. Now in a modern system, it is copy-on-write, pointing initially to the same VM pages, but this is not required by the semantics of fork. In any case, as soon as the child writes to memory, he'll be writing into a private copy of, at least, that page.

Comment: @DoxyLover Ah, yes... Thanks for the clarification. I was actually thinking of `vfork()` there apparently...

Comment: @twalberg writing to memory in the child of a `vfork` is undefined behavior (as is basically anything else except calling an `exec`-variant). `vfork` was a performance hack to speed up the very common `fork`-and-`exec` pattern. It is unnecessary on systems like linux that have a copy-on-write `fork`.